# Launching Cloud Data Flow task failes with IllegalStateException Failed to resolve MavenResource

Tags: java, maven, amazon-s3, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to register an application in Spring Cloud Data Flow server through UI. I am using an internal S3 maven repo where my artifact is published and available currently.

I have custom maven repo configured with my data flow server as below based on this [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/html/howto.html) (Section B.1). Also created an user in AWS with read access to pull the artifact.

```
{
    "maven": {
        "local-repository": "local",
        "remote-repositories": {
            "repo1": {
                "url": "s3://custom-maven-repo.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/release",
                "auth": {
                    "username": "<aws-access-key-id>",
                    "password": "<aws-secret-key>"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Though app registration is successful, I am unable to successfully launch a task based on this app. I am receiving the below error.

```
{
    "errors": [{
            "message": "Failed to resolve MavenResource: com.hidglobal.migration:migration-job:jar:0.0.1. Configured remote repositories: : [repo1],[springRepo]",
            "logref": "IllegalStateException",
            "_links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "/"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Is this issue is because my SCDF server is unable to connect to the remote repository? I so how do I configure s3 maven repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by making my S3 bucket as a static site (Storage) and used CloudFront to access the artifact via HTTPS URL.
Registered the app through the http url instead of maven uri